# primefaces calendar multi events

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, calendar, jsf-2.2

I use primefaces v5.3 and I have a problem about primefaces calendar events. There are 2 ajax events in a calendar.

The definition of calendar is:

```
<p:calendar value="#{bean.entity.nextDate}"
            id="calDonusTarihi" converter="calendarConverter" locale="tr"
            pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" styleClass="zorunluInputCalendar"
            size="13" onSelectUpdate=":f183">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="testEvent('dateSelect');" />
    <p:ajax event="blur" oncomplete="testEvent('blur');" />
</p:calendar>
```

The JavaScript function that named `testEvent` is:

```
testEvent = function(eventName) {
    console.log("Event is: "+eventName);
}
```

(There were other commands inside of this function. I've removed them to make it easier to read.)

The value of the calendar is null at first. Here's the problem: I open the calendar and the first time I select a date, the blur event is triggered. After the first selection, the dateSelect event is triggered for the other selection states.

When I click a date for the first time, the blur event is triggered and it prevents the date selection I want to do.

```
**Console**
Event is: blur
```

As shown below, for every click action (except for the first click) the dateSelect event runs and date is selected successfully. There is no problem at this point.

```
**Console**
Event is: dateSelect
Event is: dateSelect
Event is: dateSelect
```

Why are two events triggered when I first click a date? I just want the dateSelect event to be triggered without the blur event. How can I do this?